# How can I give seperate margin to individual control and also keeping same style in CSS for all of them HTML5

Tags: css, html

I have a collection of controls that I get from database and write in one HTML file.All these controls must have same style. But I want to give seperate margin property to each of the elements. How can I do that without changing my CSS?

Comment: "without changing my CSS" - What do you mean?  You'll have to change your CSS...

Comment: This is not even a question. Without code examples there is no way anybody here can help you. "How can I do that without changing my CSS" you want to change your CSS without changing CSS?

Comment: Nico, the thing is I want to keep a common CSS that can apply to every control. But position of each control on the screen comes from value that is stored in Database.

Comment: nice, but please append detailed examples of what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not get your question exactly, but here is how I understood your question.

I assume you wants to add the styles that needs to be applied to particular set of element and rest will be handled by css files.

There are basically three ways to apply styles:

1. Inline Style
2. css file
3. on page style

whatever style we would apply in css file, only that style properties will be overridden by on page style i.e. between .

whatever style we would apply on page i.e. between , only that style properties will be overridden by inline style.

so if you are going to apply margin to the textbox (by using inline styles) then those are the styles that are being applied to the element.

Although this is not good programming practices to apply inline style to the element.

Comment: Thanks Jenish. I got what I was looking for. It seems that inline style only overrides the respective CSS attribute and not the complete CSS. In this way I can give different margins although keeping the default style common.